# how to enter a long trade without closing previous long trade in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

Even before closing the long trade, my strategy conditions are met but still no new long trade was initiated.
[image]

How do I enter a long trade without closing the previous long trade in `Pine Script`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, visit the site below to know [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need set `pyramiding` (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy) parameter value to 2 or greater.